# NSTimer stopping in run time?

Tags: iphone

how can i stop NSTimer in runTime?

I am using the following code .but NSTimer runs again and again.(i want to repeat NStimer, i want to stop in runtime )

```
 - (void)TimerCallback
   {

  .....
  [self.tim invalidate];
      self.tim = nil;

}


-(void)timerStart
{


    self.tim = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(TimerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: I guess you are doing it correctly, not sure why NSTimer doesn't stop after invalidate message.. Is 'tim' set to retain? or copy? while declaring property

Comment: i have set as retain in propery..I have to assign copy?

Answer (score 1):

1. ***It's repeats:NO if you want it to run only once***. You have repeats:YES.
2. It is [tim invalidate] and ***not*** self.tim invalidate
3. Do ***not*** do self.tim = nil, because that is releasing it. invalidate does everything.
4. For the record, make sure your property is all correct, ie
   @property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *happyTimer;
   and
   @synthesize happyTimer;
5. For the record, you must be on the same thread.

Hope it helps.

Here is all the lines of code cut from a working production example:

```
NSTimer  *ttt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer  *ttt;
@synthesize ttt;
self.ttt = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.00
    target:self selector:@selector(ringBell) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
if ( [ttt isValid] )
   [ttt invalidate];
[ttt release]; // in dealloc
```

You need to add some debugging lines NSLog(@"I just invalidated"); and so on, to make sure you don't have some basic mistake.

Comment: hi, I want repeats:YES...I followed the instruction you told , but the timer is still running...

Comment: About point 2; both do the same.
About point 3; self.tim assigns the timer to nil. If it is (retain) releases the memory, if it's (assign) it's already released. In both cases it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Usually this problem is starting twice the timer. You can try

```
-(void)timerStart {
    [self.tim invalidate];
    self.tim = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(TimerCallback) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```